# Silverlight Programmatically select text

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am playing with a Silverlight control that has a TextBox and Button.  When I click the button (which calls SelectText below), I want to select all the text in the textbox.

Here's my code:

```
    private void SelectText()
    {
        TextBox tb = this.txtFirstName;
        tb.SelectionStart = 0;
        tb.SelectionLength = 3;
        // tb.Select(0, this.txtFirstName.Text.Trim().Length - 1);
        // tb.SelectAll();
        // tb.Text = String.Empty;
    }
```

The commented code is what I tried already, but neither is working.

Anyone have suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: btw.. I am aware that the // tb.Text = String.Empty clears the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to give focus to the textbox to see the actual selection happening (either before or after selecting, it might not matter but you'll have to try):

```
private void SelectText()
    {
        TextBox tb = this.txtFirstName;
        tb.SelectionStart = 0;
        tb.SelectionLength = 3;
        // tb.Select(0, this.txtFirstName.Text.Trim().Length - 1);
        // tb.SelectAll();
        // tb.Text = String.Empty;
        tb.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

SelectAll() works -- I've used it more than once. Is something manipulating the text box after this method happens?

Comment: No, but I have my controls within a grid, I'm wondering if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick for the entire User Control.

```cs
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
            tb.SelectAll();
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The focus solution worked for me, but sometimes I get this ExecutionEngineException during the SelectAll() and it's totally bogus! Even a try...catch won't stop it and there's no more details about the error.