# Silverlight C# - Set selection in textbox via code?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, web-applications, silverlight-4.0

I'm working on a spellcheck function for my app, and want to have the word that's currently being looked at highlighted. I'm tracking the char count as I loop through the words in the textbox, so I know where to set the selection at.

I've tried `txtArticle.Select(0, 10);` just as a test, as well as setting the `txtArticle.SelectionStart` and `txtArticle.SelectionLength` properties, but the textbox doesn't show anything highlighted. What's the dealio?

Actual code I've tried:

```
txtArticle.SelectionStart = charCount;
txtArticle.SelectionLength = checkedWord.Length;
```

as well as

```
txtArticle.Select(charCount, checkedWord.Length);
```

I've positively no idea what I'm doing wrong, unless you can't set what's selected in the TextBox via code, which I just can't imagine is the case. Is there perhaps some extra property that I need to set for the TextBox itself?

Thanks yet again!

-Sootah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation on MSDN of [TextBox.SelectionStart Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) has an example that works. This states that programmatic text selection is actually supported in `Silverlight`.

Looks like something else is going wrong in your application. When do you call this code? Try calling it after everything is loaded, and rendered on screen. May be on a click of a button.

If above does not work, create a sample application/page and try to follow MSDN example. When you get it working, try to figure out why it doesn't work in your application.

Comment: Actually found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652467/silverlight-programmatically-select-text - apparently you have to give the TextBox focus after setting the selection in order for it to show up for whatever reason. Worked for me.